# Polish characters receive messages imap

Tags: c#, imap, chars, polish

I have problem with Polish characters (ś,ć,ż,ź,ń,ó) 
When I receive body of mail i get "??" for everyone Polish char.

```
   MailMessage temp_message = receive.get_message(mail);
   temp_message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28592);
```

this is result :

[image]

UTF 8 , 16 not work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't strange since you can't convert a string from one encoding to another. What you are doing doesn't make any sense at all.

The `MailMessage` class supports setting the encoding, which is a much better option that converting around. Just set the [`BodyEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) to whatever you need, preferably UTF-8 or UTF-16 since that is the best option for international characters.

Comment: I wrote :  temp_message.BodyEncoding=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
but this solution didn't work for me

Comment: Did you remove all your converting around? What is the original input string?

Comment: So they are already screwed up in the string itself. Where do you get it from?

Comment: receive mail : MailMessage message = imap.GetMessage(uid);

Comment: What is `imap`? And where is that `GetMessage` method? Is that something of yourself?

Comment: Yes, that one is broken. It reads using ASCII: `string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mem.ToArray());`.

Comment: Thank you , sorry for the primitive issue but I'm beginning career with the programming

Comment: No problem. Try to change `ASCII` to `UTF8` there and see if it works.